# Core.js 12799: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'tr'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular9

This is the cart-details component html file , on which i am trying to loop items i have received from cart service which my cart-details component ts file has subscribed  . I am trying to loop through the items getting the error that the it cannot bind with ng for loop . Please help!

```
<div class="main-content">
   <div class="section-content section-content-p30">
       <div class="container-fluid">

           <table class="table table-bordered">
               <tr>
                   <th width="20%">Product Image</th>
                   <th width="50%">Product Detail</th>
                   <th width="30%"></th>
               </tr>

               <tr *ngFor="let tempCartItem of cartItems">
                   <td>
                       <img src="{{ tempCartItem.imageUrl }}" class="img-responsive" width="150px" />
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <p>{{ tempCartItem.name }}</p>
                       <p>{{ tempCartItem.unitPrice  }}</p>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <div class="items">
                           <label>Quantity:</label> {{ tempCartItem.quantity }}
                       </div>

                       <p class="mt-2">Subtotal: {{ tempCartItem.quantity *  tempCartItem.unitPrice  }}</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               <tr >
                   <td colspan="2"></td>
                   <td style="font-weight: bold">
                       <p>Total Quantity: {{ totalQuantity }}</p>
                       <p>Shipping: FREE</p>
                       <p>Total Price: {{ totalPrice  }}</p>
                   </td>
               </tr>

           </table>

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`NgFor` is a structural directive which is located in the `CommonModule`.

Please import `CommonModule` and add it in the imports array the module in which you are using `NgFor`.

Also, you are using `ngFor` in your code.

Are you sure, you are getting `Can't bind to ngForOf error ?`